# rewrite htaccess subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Mysite's running normally with the code rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#rewrite www.mysite.com/page.php?page=ID => www.mysite.com/ID
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1
```

1. It's running okay, but if the ID has a dot (.), it's not working? So
   how do I fix this?

   `#rewrite www.mysite.com/game/play.php?g=IDgame => www.mysite.com/game/IDgame
    RewriteRule ^game/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /game/play.php?g=$1`

   It's working fine :)
2. I add subdomain for mysite is: m.mysite.com
   I want to rewrite:
   `m.mysite.com/game/play.php?g=IDgame => m.mysite.com/game/IDgame`

   How do I code this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a list of characters the id *might* contain, it is often easier to have a list of characters the id certainly cannot contain. In your case it can most likely not contain a slash. You could therefore match with `([^/]+)`. You want to explicitely exclude play.php from matching as well, which you can do with a rewrite condition.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/game/play\.php
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+)/?$ /game/play.php?g=$1
```

As for your m.mysite subdomain. Make sure that the virtual host for both www.mysite and m.mysite point to the same directory. If your dns is configured properly it should internally rewrite your mobile game urls to the same file.